# Why do waves, specifically light, diffract through a slit?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I've been wondering this for a while now, and have thus far only come across answers that seem to use an equation as an explanation. I've also looked at Huygens' principle (albeit not in-depth), but this doesn't make much logical sense to me.

I'd sincerely appreciate if anyone could shed any light on the topic for me (pardon the pun :P), or try to explain Huygens' principle to me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically waves don't have a direction. There is nothing stopping them going in all directions after the slit, so they do. The real question is why they only go in one direction before the slit!

Comment: Waves do have a direction, though? I'm not understanding your answer

Comment: Drop a stone in a pond. Which direction do the waves go?

Comment: Turn on a laser pen, which way does the light travel?

Comment: All directions, but it's not just one light source, but a trillion different light sources all at the front of the laser pen. (This is Huygen's principle) If you're in front, you see the sum of all the point sources. If you're on the side, most of them cancel each other out.

Comment: (the reason I didn't make the above comments an answer is because I would have to draw diagrams. Someone else can draw them and make a proper answer!)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say haha, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/444894/why-exactly-does-diffraction-occur

Comment: The answer to that question makes sense to me regarding water waves (pressure differences cause them to spread out) but with light, I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Re, "turn on a laser pen," FYI: The width of that laser beam is 3+ orders of magnitude greater than the wavelength of the light. If we were comparing that to ripples on the surface of a pond, it would be like ripples 10cm apart passing through a 200m wide opening in a wall. Looking down on that opening from above, if you were high enough to take in the whole opening in a single glance, the diffraction at the edges would be pretty hard to notice.

Comment: @RossBeesley well light works the same as water waves because they're both waves. DON'T think about photons.

Comment: Water waves and light waves have some fundamental differences as well, example water waves show no "interference" pattern thru a single slit whereas light does! See answer below.

Comment: @PhysicsDave re, "water waves show no interference pattern..." Are you sure about that? I think this experiment shows otherwise: https://techtv.mit.edu/videos/3470-ripple-tank-single-and-double-slit-diffraction-and-interference Wait for the part that's captioned, "Wider single slit," and watch carefully what happens as they crank up the frequency of the excitation.

Comment: See this MIT presentation on page 10, it is not conclusive.  Also the pattern you mention is likely reflection off the slit sides which are rather thick. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_007S11_lec27.pdf

Comment: @SolomonSlow -see my comment above.Also sound waves show interferences in a closed room or 2 slits, but not for a single aperture radiating into an open space.

Answer (score 1):

A plane wave, by construction, has all frequency components in the direction perpendicular to propagation. Now you let that impinge on a slit (or multiple slits) - you are now altering those frequency components, and what comes through the slit(s) is no longer a plane wave but the Fourier transform of the real space slits.

Now, the link to Huygen is pretty straightforward - it is all related to the surviving frequency components between the plane wave (a solid line of the wave sources) and what comes through. The math is all the same.

Answer (score -1):

Light diffracts primarily because there is an interaction of the EM field of the aperture material with the EM field of the photon or wave.  Diffraction is interesting in itself but it is also the diffraction pattern or "interference" pattern that results which causes a lot of discussion.  The word
"interference" is historical but also somewhat misleading, 2 photons never  "interfere" or cancel, that would be a violation of energy conservation, instead photons take paths that are of certain pathlengths that are integer multiples of its wavelength ... this can explain the "interference" pattern.  Mathematically this coincides with the use of Huygens principle in double slit experiments.

For water or air you could have the movement of 1 molecule radiate outwards and effect many other molecules in a circular pattern.  Light is different, a quanta will radiate in one direction only.